# Android Use NFC To Temporary Pair Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

I am working on an application that needs to exchange some data to create an encrypted channel for communication over the internet. I will allow users to establish the keys with different methods, but I think it would be a "neat" feature to have an easy method to exchange keys.

From What I have seen you can set the PIN to use when connecting via bluetooth with reflection, but that seems extremely hacky and unreliable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchanging keys securely is pretty difficult to do. You may want to look at how this operates with SSL... SSL sets up a secure encrypted channel without the user specifying any keys at all. Pseudo-code for how this communication might work is given below:

```
 Device A:
    generate public, private key pair A
    connect to proxy server over SSL connection
    obtain connection ID from proxy server as connection ID A
    send connection ID A, public key A to device B
    wait for connection ID B, public key B from device B
    tell proxy server to connect current session to connection ID B
    encrypt session setup messages using public key B 
    send encrypted session setup message over proxy connection
    wait for encrypted session setup message from B
    decrypt encrypted session setup message using private key A
    upgrade encryption mechanism to stronger, symmetric algorithm

 Device B:
    generate public, private key pair B
    connect to proxy server over SSL connection
    obtain connection ID from proxy server as connection ID B
    send connection ID B, public key B to device A
    wait for connection ID A, public key A from device A
    tell proxy server to connect current session to connection ID A
    encrypt session setup messages using public key A 
    send encrypted session setup message over proxy connection
    wait for encrypted session setup message from A
    decrypt encrypted session setup message using private key B
    upgrade encryption mechanism to stronger, symmetric algorithm
```

However, encryption is very difficult to get right. I'd strongly recommend making the pieces that do this opensource and getting the code vetted by security experts before unleashing this on users.

Comment: I would not allow users to create there own keys, I will generate them in the application. Other than the inital keys I was planning on mimicking SSL as you say.

Comment: Ah. I was confused by "I will allow users to establish the keys with different methods"... did you mean that you will setup the connection via different methods other than NFC? Is that what you meant by that?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add NFC as an easy secondary method to setup the inital keys. I am not 100% sure how I want to estable the keys by default. Edit: This will be open source, btw.

Comment: I think the approach above should work regardless of medium. Don't rely on encryption existing in the underlying medium. Use a proxy HTTPS server in the Cloud to talk between the two devices once you exchange public keys (in the clear) and the endpoint IDs (also in the clear). This will make it so that only the exchange of (endpoint ID, public key) needs to be medium-specific (and for that, abstracting out a common interface that you can implement separately for each medium, would be a good way to design for reuse).

Comment: Ok, I think we should go back to the initial question though. How does one temporary pair via nfc.

Comment: You would do it via the Android Beam API. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p